How can I use STL sort() on a pointer to an array? (C++)
I'm doing an assignment for a class right now, which asks us to create a new array based on user input and then use STL sort from a pointer of the array. I am getting errors while doing that, however.
Here is my full code:
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
//#include <string>
#include <cctype>
//#include <cmath>
//#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int numberOfScores;
double *testScore; // Pointer to dynamically allocated array of scores
double ave; // Average score

void getScores();

int main(){
    getScores();
    sort(testScore.begin(), testScore.end());
    cout << showpoint << fixed << setprecision(2);
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(testScore); i++){
        cout << *(testScore + i) << endl;
    }
    return(0);
}

void getScores(){
    cout << "How many scores are you entering?\n"; 
    cin >> numberOfScores;
    while (numberOfScores <= 0){
        cout << "please enter a valid input \n";
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(1000,'\n');
        cin >> numberOfScores;
    }

    testScore = new double[numberOfScores];
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfScores; i++){
        cout << "Please enter a score:\n";
        cin >> testScore[i];
        while (testScore[i] < 0 || testScore[i] > 100){
            cout << "please enter a valid input \n";
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(1000,'\n');
            cin >> testScore[i];
        }  
    }
}

The error I get from using sort():

expression must have class type but it has type "double *"


Side note: nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that std::endl does. Use '\n' to end a line unless you have a good reason not to.

testScore is a pointer; it doesn't have any member functions, so calling begin() and end() on it won't work. std::sort takes a pair of iterators, and pointers are valid iterators. So figure out where your data begins and where it ends, and pass those two pointers in the call to std::sort.

If you are using the standard library, there is no need for new[].  Instead use std::vector<double> testScore; and then testScore.resize(numberOfScores);

You are strongly recommended to start from The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List to avoid C++ basic questions.

int main(){ getScores(); getScores(); -- See how easy it is to get a memory leak?

Just use C++ as it is intended to be use use std:vector<double> testScores(numberOfScores);. In current C++ you should hardly ever have to use new/delete manually (and it isn't even recommended to do so anymore unless you are writing your own more low level datastructures). So whoever is teaching you to do it like this is not doing a godd job

@user4581301 • my former coworker — Alexander Stepanov — would greatly approve of your distinction between STL and Standard C++ Library.  Only about a third of STL made it into C++98.

@PeteBecker not to mention the global variables stuff going on...

testScore is a double* and doesn't have member functions like begin() and end(). However, a double* works fine as an iterator so you can just supply testScore as the begin iterator and testScore + numberOfScores as the end iterator.
Note also that sizeof(testScore) will give you the size of the pointer, not the number of elements. You need to use numberOfScores when iterating.
Example:
int main(){
    getScores();
    std::sort(testScore, testScore + numberOfScores);
    //        ^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    std::cout << std::showpoint << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2);
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfScores; i++){ // not sizeof(testScore)
        //              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        std::cout << testScore[i] << '\n'; // instead of *(testScore + i)
    }
}

Also note that the program will leak memory since you don't delete[] testScore when you're done with it.
